# Enviar una informacion a 2 formularios distintos

Tags: php, javascript

Necesito enviar esta informacion a estos 2 formularios (pedidos, sells) pero como pueden observar va directamente solo a Pedidos. Como puedo hacer que esa informacion vaya a los 2 formularios?

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
$pedido =  new PedidoData();
$pedido->nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$pedido->apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
$pedido->telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$pedido->direccion = $_POST["direccion"];
$pedido->fechapedido = $_POST["fechapedido"];
$pedido->entrega = $_POST["entrega"];
$pedido->add();
if($found){
    Core::redir("./?view=pedidos");
}else{
    Core::redir("./?view=sells");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Y si quitas el if? Así quedan los dos Core::redir uno seguido del otro

Comment: No puedes redirigir a dos páginas, el navegador solo va a mostrar una.